# Hotkeys to toggle draw-view in Unity

Tags: unity

Using Unity (2109.1.3f1) is there a way to switch the scene view's `Shading Mode`/`Draw Mode` from `Wireframe` to `Shaded`?
(eg. press `4` for `Wireframe`, `5` for `Shaded`)

I've looked in the Shortcuts Editor, but "Wireframe" doesn't appear in any list of commands, and I don't see anything under the `Scene Visibilty` or `Scene View` Categories that look appropriate either.

The docs only describe how to toggle this through the `Scene view control bar`, but it seems silly that it wouldn't be possible to map that operation to a key combination.

Comment: Have you tried adding your own hotkey to do this with an editor script?

Comment: That hadn't occurred to me; I'll have to look into how to do that, thanks!